# Where can I see my Laravel configuration in production: Example db connection, mail server

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean

Where can I see my Laravel configuration in production? I need to confirm the connection string of the production Laravel app, as well as mail server and other configurations.

I can't find the config.php file. I have a droplet in Digital Ocean an can access to it, but cannot understand the way this is being stored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In parrent directory .env

Comment: If i run printdev i see some variables but not the ones I'm looking for. Mail setup, connectio string. Shouldn't be here?

Comment: You should be able to 'cat .env' to see the contents. 

How are the contents of the file being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your Laravel DB connection, mail server, etc.. in the **.env** file which is present in the parent directory. If those items are missing, then you can check them in the **config/app.php** file.

Comment: All options were right. I've manage to understand how they were managing this setup. They were doing it with Laravel Forge. Thanks.